# django model depth search

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have three models,

- `MTI` = Material Information
- `MTD` = Material Description
- `MTIIMAGE` = for each color and size there is a picture

I am trying to create a query that returns distinct colors, however the color results I am getting are not unique:

```
mymti[0].mtd_set.all()
[mtd: 1234567 - Medium black, mtd: 1122334455 - Medium pink, mtd: 12345678
- Large black]
```

How can I get distinct color from this query so that the result will be

> [mtd: 1234567 - Medium black, mtd: 1122334455 - Medium pink]

```
class mti(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    item = models.ForeignKey(item)
    country = models.ForeignKey(country)
    dept = models.ForeignKey(dept)
    fabric = models.ForeignKey(fabric)
    sesason = models.ForeignKey(season)
    sale = models.FloatField()
    endUser = models.FloatField()
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000,blank=True,null=True)
    year = models.CharField(max_length=255,default=strftime("%Y", gmtime()))
    front_page = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="Front Page",default=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    stamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s - %s' % (self.name, self.description)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "MTI"
        verbose_name_plural = verbose_name

class mtd(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    barcode = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    mti = models.ForeignKey(mti)
    size = models.ForeignKey(size)
    color = models.ForeignKey(color)
    weight = models.FloatField()
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "MTD"
        verbose_name_plural = verbose_name
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s - %s %s' % (self.barcode, self.size.name,self.color.name)

class mtiimage(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    color = models.ForeignKey(color)
    mtd= models.ForeignKey(mtd)
    mti=models.ForeignKey(mti)
    pic1 = models.ImageField(verbose_name="Product 1 Image",upload_to='product')
    pic2 = models.ImageField(verbose_name="Product 2 Image",upload_to='product')
    pic3 = models.ImageField(verbose_name="Product 3 Image",upload_to='product')
    stamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

     def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s - %s' % (self.mtd.barcode, self.color.name)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "MTI Pic"
        verbose_name_plural = verbose_name
```

My view is

```
mydept = dept.objects.get(pk=deptid)
mymti = mti.objects.filter(dept=mydept).select_related()
```

My template

```
{% for i in mymti %}
{% for m in i.mtd_set.all %}{{m.mtiimage_set.all.0.pic1.url}}{{m.mtiimage_set.all.0.color.name|lower}}{% endfor   %}
   {% endfor %}
```

Comment: -1: please try and reduce the quantity of your problematic code instead of expecting people to read through 50 lines of model code looking for the relevant fields

Comment: It smells like your models are poorly designed.  What exactly are you trying to acheive?  How did you select medium black over large black?  While you explain your goal, get rid of anything unrelated as @Caspar suggested.

Answer (score 0):

i solved this issue by redesign my model, by putting mtiimage foreign key to mti
which is i can query it directly

for n in mti.mtiimage_set.all()
    print n.color.name